# Hardware RAID10 HPA recovery

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, raid, data-recovery

I have a hardware RAID 1+0 based on external CFI-B8253JDGG DAS. It was connected to PC with eSATA and contains 4x1TB HDD (Total capacity is 1.82TB in RAID10). Some days ago I tried to connect the DAS to another PC but something went wrong... My RAID in Windows7 looked like single partition with capacity 931.51Gb RAW. (Later I realized that the problem was in Gigabyte motherboard,  AHCI/IDE settings and maybe in hands.so).
I spent some time and used a lot of programs trying to recover data from RAID and separated drives reassembled to virtual RAID (all operations as readonly). So I can see full directory tree but the most part of the files is unreadable.

One interesting thing I found (/dev/sdc is my RAID10):

```
$ sudo hdparm -N /dev/sdc

/dev/sdc:
 max sectors   = 1953403071/3906863104, HPA is enabled
```

but if I try to set max HPA to "default" or disable

```
$ sudo hdparm -N 3906863104 /dev/sdc

/dev/sdc:
 setting max visible sectors to 3906863104 (temporary)
 SET_MAX_ADDRESS failed: Input/output error
 max sectors   = 1953403071/3906863104, HPA is enabled
```

Other programs for changing HPA parameters like Victoria, HDD Capacity Restore Tool have no success.

I tested the same thing with another single 1TB drive:

- connected to new PC
- have a 32MB RAW patrition
- hdparm -N XXXXXXXXXX /dev/sdX
- successfully mounted partition with all data

Any ideas for changing HPA to "default"/"factory" for this RAID10?

---

UPD:

```
# hdparm -K 1 /dev/sdc

/dev/sdc:
 setting drive keep features to 1 (on)
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(keepsettings) failed: Input/output error


# hdparm -Np3906863104 /dev/sdc

/dev/sdc:
 setting max visible sectors to 3906863104 (permanent)
 SET_MAX_ADDRESS failed: Input/output error
 max sectors   = 1953403071/3906863104, HPA is enabled
```

I tried to use `hdparm` and other programs like HDAT2, Victoria 3.52, DiskCheckup.

Comment: 1) Can you verify that the new/current config is still set to RAID10? If it is seeing one drive rather then an array (or a 4drive RAID1E) then the size is already at max.
2) Are the drives identical? If not setting them to identical size (with a bit space to spare in case a replacement drive is smaller) is a good thing.
3) Why not recreate? Wipe. Create new array. Restore from backup.  That might take a few hours over SATA but you easily lost those hours already by trying to get it to work.

Comment: 1) This Direct Attached Storage configures with DIP-switches at back panel. Yes, it is set to RAID10

Comment: 2) Yes, all drives are identical, all drives (separately) shows identical block numbers and sizes; 3) Of course, all data was restored from backups, but it is too easy to wipe ^_^ I want to solve this problem anyway.

Comment: What happens if you use either  `hdparm -Np3906863104 --yes-i-know-what-i-am-doing /dev/sdc` (HPA on, but max sectors visible) or when you try to retain hdparm settings after a [software] reset with `hdparm -K 1 /dev/sdc` ?

Comment: Answered in the first post. (UPD:)

Answer (score 1):

Answer from CFI Group technical support.

> Unfortunately, this is limitation of RAID controller. You can not change HPA parameters. To solve the
>   problem, you need to re-create the array, but all data will be lost.

Comment: +1 just for posting an answer. (too many people sadly do not).